# Date Lookup from same column based on values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup

I have a table that lists several tasks and the day that they will or have taken place. [Task Key] is the primary key. [Task Type] groups together tasks that the same.

**Task Table**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Another table tells me if a Task is Current, Baseline or a Snapshot.

**Category Table**

[image]

I want to create a table that adds the baseline date for each task in another column

[image]

I have only gotten this far. I know there are windows function ROW_NUMBER and LEAD and LAG, but can't figure out how to implement it.

```
SELECT
    ta.[Task Key],
    ca.[Task Type],
    ta.[Task Type],
    ta.[Task Name],
    ta.[Task Date]
FROM
    TASK ta
LEFT JOIN
    CATEGORY ca
ON
    ta.[Task Key] = ca.[Task Key]
```

Comment: can you add data in text format? this can be solved by some window aggregation

Comment: SQLfiddle with schema definition here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e9573/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Max() OVER()`

```
DECLARE @Task TABLE
(
Task_Key int identity(1,1),
Task_Type int,
Task_Name nvarchar(20),
Task_Date nchar(9)
)


DECLARE @Category TABLE
(
    Task_Key int identity(1, 1),
    Category nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Task(task_type,Task_name,Task_Date)
VALUES
(N'1',N'Laundry',N'12-Apr-23'),
(N'1',N'Laundry',N'15-Mar-23'),
(N'1',N'Laundry',N'02-Dec22'),
(N'2',N'Cooking',N'14-Dec-24'),
(N'2',N'Cooking',N'01-Sep-23'),
(N'3',N'Hovering',N'12-Apr-23'),
(N'3',N'Hovering',N'04-Dec-22'),
(N'3',N'Hovering',N'19-Jan-22')

INSERT INTO @Category(Category)
VALUES
(N'Current'),
(N'BaseLine'),
(N'Snapshot'),
(N'Current'),
(N'BaseLine'),
(N'Current'),
(N'BaseLine'),
(N'Snapshot')

SELECT T.Task_Key,T.Task_Type,T.Task_Name,T.Task_Date Date,
MAX(CASE WHEN C.Category = 'BaseLine' THEN T.Task_Date END) OVER(PARTITION BY T.TASK_NAME) [Basline Date],
MAX(CASE WHEN C.Category = 'Current' THEN T.Task_Date END) OVER(PARTITION BY T.TASK_NAME) [Current Date]
FROM @Task T
JOIN @Category C ON T.Task_Key = C.Task_Key
ORDER BY T.Task_Key
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a common table expression to first find the baseline date for each task_type, then subsequently left outer join to that (to avoid dropping rows where there might not be a baseline date). Something like:

```
WITH b AS (
    SELECT t.task_type, 
           t.task_date as baseline_date 
      FROM task t 
      JOIN category c ON t.task_key = c.task_key 
     WHERE c.category = 'baseline'
)
SELECT t.task_key, 
       t.task_type, 
       t.task_name, 
       t.task_date, 
       b.baseline_date 
  FROM task t 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b on t.task_type = b.task_type
```